# Duplicate assemblies in AppDomain

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-assembly, appdomain, .net-core-3.1

I ported my WPF application from .NET Framework 4.7 to .NET Core 3.1 but I am facing issue that I could not solve.

I am using singleton for some app logic. This singleton needs to be initialized before it can be used. So at the start of the application I create it as a static reference and initialize it. So far so good. I have some xml settings that gets deserialized during the startup process. I am using ordinary framework xml serializers. I access that singleton during OnDeserialized method. But now the static reference is null. Static constructor gets called twice. So I tried to solve that and I noticed that my AppDomain contains multiple assemblies (my assemblies that are referenced in app projects) that are same, with the same version, the same target source file. I don't perform manual assembly load anywhere. I also noticed that right before OnDeserialized is hit, there are some assembly loads performed by the framework that cause duplicate assemblies to get loaded to my AppDomain. It worked without problem under .NET Framework 4.7.

Here is simplified structure and code that reflects my real implementation.

Project structure and dependencies

[image: project structure]

App startup

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var resource = CreateResourceSingleton();
    resource.Initialize();

    LoadSettings();
}
```

Part of the settings

```
[OnDeserialized]
private void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext c)
{
    AccessSingleton();
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

I found that I could get around this problem by manually go through the assembly reference tree and loading all assemblies (have to allow the duplicates here otherwise it doesn't work) at the startup, but that is quite the performance hit as it loads hundreds of them inside the AppDomain. Then it works even with duplicates inside the domain.

```
public void PreloadAssemblies()
{
    var loadedAssemblies = new List<string>();
    var assembliesToCheck = new Queue<System.Reflection.Assembly>();

    assembliesToCheck.Enqueue(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());

    while (assembliesToCheck.Any())
    {
        var assemblyToCheck = assembliesToCheck.Dequeue();

        foreach (var reference in assemblyToCheck.GetReferencedAssemblies())
        {
            if (!loadedAssemblies.Contains(reference.FullName))
            {
                try
                {
                    var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(reference);
                    assembliesToCheck.Enqueue(assembly);
                    loadedAssemblies.Add(reference.FullName);
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So what is my question?
How to get around the fact that there are assembly duplicates inside my AppDomain and each such assembly has its own static variables.

Comment: This is fairly convoluted, so what is your most immediate problem... Do you have code for it

Comment: I added some additional info